# NSString to NSURL?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, foundation

Trying to convert a string to NSURL and this is not happening.

```
barcodeTextLabel.text = foundCode.barcodeString;
urlToGrab = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", foundCode.barcodeString]; // foundCode.barcodeString is an NSString
```

`urlToGrab` shows the following "error invalid CFStringRef"

Comment: CAn u give ur code with some more details like urlToGrab  belongs to Wat kind of DataType

Comment: How do you expect to get a NSURL from the `+stringWithFormat:` method?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is how you create an `NSURL` from an `NSString`:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"];
```

Comment: NSURL is an object, so you are missing the *. NSURL *url

Answer (score 3):

You can use following for creating the file path to url.

```
NSURL *yourURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/xyz/Desktop/abc.sqlite"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If `foundCode.barcodeString` is the string you want as your URL, then (like the above answer) use the `NSURL` class method `URLWithString:(NSString *)`.

Your code should look like:

```
NSURL *urlToGrab = [NSURL URLWithString:foundCode.barcodeString];
```

Where is your error coming into to play? The way your code is, urlToGrab is an instance of `NSString`. I would imagine you would get an error like you described if you tried to make an HTTP request on an `NSString` rather than `NSURL`.

Answer (score -2):

Swapnali patil's answer works, but I will add an explanation.

You will get a `nil` if the format of NSString doesn't fit file criteria for NSURL (`file:///xxx/file.ext`).

My needs were with loading a JPG image via URL file path to nsdata; `NSURL * u=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:fpath]` returned nil, but `NSURL *yourURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fpath]` as in mentioned answer worked. A URL for files will be `file:///users/xxx/pic.jpg` format and give disk access. `NSURL * u=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:(NSString*) ]` will also give nil object if nsstring is web URL but if missing `http://`